# MacBook Pro Display Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I own a 11 month old MacBook Pro 13" with Apple Care. From the last 2 months, I've noticed a bright line on my screen which is about 0.5 cm in size. Should I be worried? Will Apple be able to repair it?

Comment: No need to worry as you have Apple Care. If you are in India, you can go to any Aurthorized Service Centre such as Imagine and get repaired for free.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should not be worried however since you do have Apple Care I'd backup your files using Time Machine and then make arrangements to have it looked at and repaired.  As to whether or not they can fix it or just replace the part(s) in question that will be decide by Apple however since it's under warranty the'll have to fix it or replace it.

From [Contact Apple Support](https://getsupport.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.action?caller=rcon) ...

> A Genius Bar reservation is an easy way to get hardware repairs, but
>   we can solve many issues over the phone or by chat. Tell us a little
>   about what’s going on and we’ll suggest the right support option.